# Sed extract numbers: how to replace non-numeric characters with a single space?

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to pull out all the (real/floating point) numbers from the string `(-5.2,-1.9) node (v1) {} rectangle (8.5,-5.3);`, such that the numbers are separated with a single space. So I tried this:

```
$ echo "(-5.2,-1.9) node (v1) {} rectangle (8.5,-5.3);" \
  | sed 's/[^[0-9\.\-]]*/ /g'
 -5.2 -1.9         1                8.5 -5.3
```

As you can see, the numbers are extracted fine - but there are a lot of spaces in-between them, occasionally?!

This was my reasoning: tell `sed` to match characters of all digits, including period and minus ..`[0-9\.\-]`.., then match all/any characters which do not belong to this set `[^[`...`]]`, and match a sequence of zero or more occurrences ...]`*` of characters in this set (the "non-numbers") - and replace them with a single space ...`/ /`g, for all occurrences ...`/g`.

With this, I expected when `sed` encounters say `) node (v` substring, it would replace it with a single space, but it doesn't. Why?

What would be the correct regex to extract all numbers, separated only by a single space - regardless of the number of non-numeric digits separating them in the original string?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'd like to know why the `'s/[^[0-9\.\-]]*/ /g'` regex leaks spaces. This is how I imagine the process to occur, with indicated input stream, character under test (testchar), matchbuffer (matchbuf), and output stream:

```
input   :                ) node (v1) {} rectang....
testchar:              `9`
matchbuf:
output  : ...-5.2,-1.

* does testchar `9` not belong to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-}?
* no - copy to output

input   :                 node (v1) {} rectangl....
testchar:              `)`
matchbuf:
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9

* does testchar `)` not belong to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-}?
* yes - copy to match buffer

input   :                node (v1) {} rectangle....
testchar:              ` `
matchbuf: `)`
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9

* does testchar ` ` not belong to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-}?
* yes - copy to match buffer

input   :                ode (v1) {} rectangle ....
testchar:              `n`
matchbuf: `) `
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9

* does testchar `n` not belong to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-}?
* yes - copy to match buffer

input   :                de (v1) {} rectangle (....
testchar:              `o`
matchbuf: `) n`
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9

* does testchar `o` not belong to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-}?
* yes - copy to match buffer

input   :                e (v1) {} rectangle (8....
testchar:              `d`
matchbuf: `) no`
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9

...

input   :                ) {} rectangle (8.5,-5....
testchar:              `1`
matchbuf: `) node (v`
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9

* does testchar `1` not belong to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,-}?
* no - replace matchbuf with /` `/, copy to output; copy `1` to output

input   :                 {} rectangle (8.5,-5.....
testchar:              `)`
matchbuf: ``
output  : ...-5.2,-1.9 1

...
```

Obviously, this is not how the matching algorithm works (else I wouldn't be asking the question `:)` ) - so what I want to know is, where am I going wrong in my understanding of how the algorithm works?

Answer (score 3):

Just increase the substitutions.

```
$ echo "(-5.2,-1.9) node (v1) {} rectangle (8.5,-5.3);"   | sed 's/[^[0-9\.\-]]*/ /g;s/ \+/ /g;s/^ \+\| \+$//g'
-5.2 -1.9 1 8.5 -5.3
```

`s/ \+/ /g;` - Replaces one or more spaces with a single space.

`s/^ \+\| \+$//g` - From the resultant string, it replaces all the spaces at the start or at the end with an empty string.

**OR**

```
$ echo "(-5.2,-1.9) node (v1) {} rectangle (8.5,-5.3);"   | sed 's/[^0-9.-]\+/ /g;s/^ \+\| \+$//g'
-5.2 -1.9 1 8.5 -5.3
```

Since `*` matches the previous token **zero** or more times, it would do a match on the boundary which exists just before to the non-matching character.

Ok , let me explain the problem with the below simple example.

**Example 1:**

```
$ echo 'foo234bar' | sed 's/[a-z]*/ /g'
 2 3 4
```

`*` repeats the pevious token that is `[a-z]` zero or more times. So every non-matching character, this pattern would match the boundary which exists just before to the non-matching character. `[a-z]*`
 matches greedily the string `foo`. And there comes the non-matching character `2`. So this pattern would match the boundary which exists just before to the `2`. Then it move on to the next character ie, `3` . It woun't be matched by the given patter, so again it matches the boundary before 3 likewise for 4 and greedily matches the remaining `bar` string. If a character is not matched then it skips that particular character. Finally we have three boundaries matched. Now sed tries to replace the matched boundaries and characters with a space.

That's why you got spaces before the digits.

**Example 2:**

```
$ echo 'foo234bar' | sed 's/[a-z]\+/ /g'
 234
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times. If it finds a non-matching character then it suddenly skips to the next character. It won't match any boundary.

So in the above example , `foo`, `bar` got matched. These two strings are replaced by a space character. Thats why you got only two spaces(one at the start and one at the end) in the final output.

Comment: Many thanks, @AvinashRaj, +1 - that works great, but I also wanted to know what is wrong with my understanding of the original post's sed pattern; edited the OP to clarify. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` to get all number out of a line:

```
awk -F "[^-0-9.]*" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:" ")}' file
```

Eks

```
echo "(-5.2,-1.9) node (v1) {} rectangle (8.5,-5.3);" | awk -F "[^-0-9.]*" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:" ")}'
-5.2 -1.9 1 8.5 -5.3
```

We just tell that filed separator can not contain anything with numbers inn it. Then just print the field.